# Computations of Durbin-Watson quantiles

Tags: statistical-significance, autocorrelation, quantiles, quadratic-form

For some educational reasons I am currently trying to re-compute Durbin and Watsons (1951, Paper II) critical values of the lower and upper bounds of their Test-Statistic (dL and dH), and also table extensions like the one of Savin and White (1977). I know that this has no practical relevance as we can compute exact p-values using pan/gradsol algorithm, but as mentioned, this is just for educational purposes.
The only promising source I found on the web was a 2002 Handbook Publication "Computing the Distribution of a quadratic form in normal variables" by R.W. Farebrother. However, I am stuck in section 4 in which he writes, that one can determine the bounds by setting g = 1 and solving the equation

Pr[ sum( (lambda - c) * z ²) ] = alpha         (4.1)

for c". My problem is that I can evaluate the left-hand side of (4.1) calculating the eigenvalues lambda and applying pan/gadsol algorithm but I do not know how to solve (4.1) for c. The only (and maybe naive) ideas that I have are (i) to reverse the pan/gradsol algorithm such that it returns quantiles (which seems to be a quite tedious task) or to do a binary search over function values of pan/gradsol function (which is computationally inefficient). How exactly are the quantile-tables of dL and dH generated?
The other problem I have is to implement the original Imhof/Koerts/Abrahamse algorithm "fquad" for the above purpose as it seems not to evaluate the same quadratic form as pan/gradsol does. How do I have to use/modify this algorithm such that it is fully compatible with pan/gradsol?

I know that these questions might be trivial to some of you but any help would be highly appreciated.